# SPSSIOError: format for 'variable' misspecified (A'XXX)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I've loaded a SAV-dataset (SPSS-dataset) using the SavLoader from the package 'savReaderWriter'. The raw data is loaded as an pandas dataframe whereas the meta information (variable labels, value labels, formats etc.) are loaded as a dictionary called meta_dict. Saving the loaded dataset/ pandas dataframe with SavWriter works perfectly:

> ```
> array = dataframe.where(dataframe.notnull(), None).values
> ```

```
with sav.SavWriter(path, var_names, var_types, **meta_kwargs) as writer:
    writer.writerows(array)
```

But if I cut off the strings of one of the variables in the dataframe and also adjust the formats in the meta_dict to the same length it does not work any more:

Cutting off the strings of the variable:

> dataframe[var] = dataframe[var].apply(lambda x: unicode(x)[:250])

Adjusting the format of the variable in the meta_dict:

> meta_dict["formats"][var] = "A" + str(250)

These operations both work. But saving the adjusted dataframe and meta_dict using SavWriter (see above) does not work any more!
I get the following error:

> SPSSIOError: format for 'var' misspecified ('A250')

Where's the mistake in my code?

Comment: Why `dataframe[var] = dataframe[var].apply(lambda x: unicode(x)[:250])` and not `dataframe[var] = dataframe[var].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:250])`?

Comment: I use Python 2.7 and I also have signs like ä,ü and ö in my strings. If I don't use unicode, I get an ascii/unicode error.

Comment: Maybe `A250` is not the correct format here. I just looked at the [`savutil` source code](https://github.com/angloc/savutil/blob/master/savdllwrapper.py) and they have "SPSS_FMT_A" listed as the format for strings. Maybe you can try `meta_dict["formats"][var] = "SPSS_FMT_A"` instead?

Comment: Tanks for your help but unforunately that does not work :(. Python raises a ValueError: "Unknown format 'SPSS_FMT_A' or invalid width for variable 'var'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPSS data dictionary contains two relevant attribues for your problem:

1. **formats** (the one you've already changed)
2. **varTypes** (the one you're missing)

The **format** defines the *meaning* (e.g. a numeric value can be interpreted as a plain number, a date, a time or a currency) whereas the **varTypes** is more fundamental as it distinguishes the underlying data representation into either a string or numerical value. For a better explanation, see [here](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-variable-types-and-formats/).

The savReaderWriter requires both properties to be in line with each other (even though I think they should also be able to behave independently). Hence, you only need to set the *varTypes* according to your *formats*, like so:

```
meta_dict["formats"][var] = "A" + str(250)
meta_dict["varTypes"][var] = 250
```